# How to use encoder factory in Symfony 2 inside the model setter?

Tags: symfony, models, code-organization

This question about Symfony 2.1

How can I encode User password with:

```
$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$user = new Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User();

$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword('ryanpass', $user->getSalt());
$user->setPassword($password);
```

And base config:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    encoders:
        Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

Inside the setter models:

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
       $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

I believe that the process of encryption password must deal by model. 
How can I use standart encoder factory inside the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entity contains data, not handles it. If you want to change data of an entity you can create the event listener and do stuff before persistence. Check [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) from the official documentation.

You can also take a look at [FosUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and its user management.

[FosUserBundle UserManager](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Doctrine/UserManager.php)

So, the main idea is to pass plain password from a form to the user entity and encode it before persitence using event listener.

Comment: Yes, entities may handle data also. For example you may add a ROLE to a user which has none in getter method as explained here: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-security/dynamic-roles
I wouldn't put everything in entity but you are setting password, and that is what the function does, so it makes sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 11):

While I agree with @Vadim that you shouldn't be leaking business logic into your model, I would be careful with deferring the hashing of the plaintext password until the `prePersist` event, for example, unless you call `persist` and `flush` right after `setPassword`. A `getPassword` call in the meantime will return the plaintext string unless you have stored it in a separate field, which could have serious consequences. Ideally the plaintext password should exist for as short a time as possible within the application's lifecycle.

I recommend using a service layer wherein a "User Manager" provides an interface to common tasks, so that you don't need to pollute your password property even temporarily:

```
class UserManager
{
    // ...
    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory)
    {
        // $encoderFactory is injected by the DIC as requested by your service configuration
        // ...
    }

    public function setUserPassword(UserInterface $user, $plaintextPassword)
    {
        $hash = $this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user)->encodePassword($plaintextPassword, null);
        $user->setPassword($hash);
    }
    // ...
}
```

In your controller for registration form submission, for instance:

```
public function userRegistrationAction()
{
    // ... 
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user = new User();
        // ...
        $this->get('my.bundle.user_manager')->setUserPassword($user, $form->get('password')->getData());
        // ...
    }
}
```