# Reset password symfony 4 (user not loggued)

Tags: symfony, symfony4, forgot-password

I have a problem when i try to reset password on a non loggued user.

Entity users :

```
class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, TwoFactorInterface, TrustedDeviceInterface  {

[...]
}
```

Reset Password Action :

```
public function forgetPassword(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $changePasswordModel = new ChangePassword();
        $form = $this->createForm(ForgetPasswordType::class, $changePasswordModel);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        $user = $em->getRepository("App:Users")->find(12);
        if (!$request->get('token') || !$user || $user->getTokenExpire() <= new \DateTime())
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("404");
        }

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $plainPassword = $form->getData()->getNewPassword();
            $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);
            $user->setPassword($encoded);
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->render('security/forget_password.html.twig', array(
            'form'    => $form->createView(),
            'success' => $success
        ));
    }
```

But i get this error :

> ```
> The User object must implement the UserInterface interface.
> ```

Exact place of this error is on :
\vendor\symfony\security\Core\Validator\Constraints\UserPasswordValidator.php :

```
[...]
 $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new ConstraintDefinitionException('The User object must 
            implement the UserInterface interface.');
        }
[...]
```

When the user is loggued it work but when an user use a reset password it's because he lost his password. So it should work when the user is not loggued.

Thanks for your help !

Alex

Comment: Just a thought...but they have deprecated that interface in SF4.1+ (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-deprecated-the-advanceduserinterface)

Comment: Also what line specifically is giving you issue? I suspect the encodePassword() - can you confirm?

Comment: The problem is that Symfony supports multiple encoders based on the user class.  When logged in the correct encoder is injected based on the currently logged in user.  If you are not logged then there is no way to determine which encoder should be used.  Instead, you need to use the EncoderFactory to select the proper encoder.  Take a look at the [unaccepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883688/how-to-use-encoder-factory-in-symfony-2-inside-the-model-setter) for an example.

Comment: @Alex.Barylski : Yes i know for the interface, i will change it. I edit with the exact line with the issue.

Comment: @Cerad : Ok i understand. I will try to use directly the encoder factory i think i dont have the choice. But i don't understand why symfony did not expect this case?

Comment: @alxb Have you got this to work?  I may have misled you on the multiple encoder guess.  It looks like you may have a listener somewhere that is trying to validate the password even though the user is not logged in.  Maybe something to do with your two factor stuff or trusted device code.

Comment: Ok finally i found the solution : I remove OldPassword field with his assert (it was idiot to ask user to set his old password in a reset password form !) and now it's work. The validate() function was call on the handleRequest, because it's a constraint on the OldPassword Field.